Best practice for sending users separate emits using socket.io
I'm making a simple React, Node web game with no database, Player objects last only for the duration of their session. When they disconnect, the socket and player SHOULD get removed at the same time.
So to send a user a separate message, I was planning on just setting the player ID as the socket.ID upon connection, and doing something like io.to(player.getID()).emit(...), where getID() just returns the socket.id.
But I read online that socket.id is reset every time a connection or reconnection occurs. So if the user disconnects from wifi for a minute and reconnects (they should stay in the game), their socket will reset and generate a new socket ID? That means that io.to(player.getID()).emit(...) wouldn't emit to the right socket, correct?
If that's the case, what's the best practice to send users private messages in socket.io in my scenario?
edit: I considered joining each user to a room ${roomCode}${username}, and using that to emit messages privately but I'm not sure it's the best idea to create a socket room for each user online?
